# Powershell Add-PSSnapin VMWare.VimAutomation.Core issues

Tags: powershell, powercli

I've just updated from Powershell 4 and PowerCLI 4.* to Powershell 5 and PowerCLI 6.*. After updating, adding/using snapin `VMWare.VimAutomation.Core` isn't working:

```
PS C:\Users\Me> Add-PSSnapin VMWare.VimAutomation.Core
Add-PSSnapin : Unexpected error: A connection core service provider is already registered. Cannot register new one.
```

When trying to remove:

```
PS C:\Users\Me> Remove-PSSnapin VMWare.VimAutomation.Core
Remove-PSSnapin : No Windows PowerShell snap-ins matching the pattern 'VMWare.VimAutomation.Core' were found. 
Check the pattern and then try the command again.
```

From `Get-PSSnapin -Registered`, I get:

```
Name        : VMware.VimAutomation.Core
PSVersion   : 4.0
Description : This Windows PowerShell snap-in contains Windows PowerShell cmdlets for managing vSphere.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled and reinstalled PowerCLI 6.3 and all was fixed. `Get-PSSnapin -Registered` now returns the following:

```
Name        : VMware.VimAutomation.Core
PSVersion   : 5.0
Description : This Windows PowerShell snap-in contains Windows PowerShell cmdlets for managing vSphere.
```

Also to note: VMware.VimAutomation.Core is both a module and a snapin in this version of PowerCLI.